# Using JSTL within JSP Pages in Struts based web app

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts, jstl

I have a Struts 1.2 based Web App which uses lot of scriptlet code in the JSP page, I wish to clean up the code by using JSTL.The Servlet Specification Level: 2.3 and JSP Specification Level: 1.2.
I am using WSAD 5.1.

I tried using `<c:if></c:if>` tag, but I get the following error on building the project.
"JSP Translate: unable to load if tag"

I have included the taglibs element for this tag library and also the TLD file in the appropriate folder.

I guess the container is not able to locate the tag handler.

It would be great if someone could share their thoughts on this.

Comment: To answer this question we need more info: what servlet container, what libraries you have installed, and what version of the servlet spec you are trying to use.  JSTL changed a lot between servlet 2.3 and 2.4.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using a version of JSTL compatible with your servlet container. For example, JSTL 1.1 is only compatible with JSP 2.0 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

instead of this or vise versa

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```